# Using XMLHttpRequest to do a get request to a var, but also creates a carriage return

Tags: javascript, dom, xmlhttprequest

Before I start, just wanted to say I'm very new to javascript. 
But I am trying to do a GET request to URL that will return a string - just some very simple text, then create a variable, and use to set an attribute for a html element.

Here is my code:

```
    var vendor;
var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}
var client = new HttpClient();
client.get('http://my.example.com/file.txt', function(response) {
    mydata = response;
    document.querySelector(".btn").setAttribute("onclick", "window.open('https://" + mydata + ".example.com')");

});
```

I want the contents of the "file.txt" to be used in the mydata var, then use setAttribute to change the onclick properties.

It does return the response, but adds a carriage return to it, and when use chrome javascript console to show the "mydata" it returns back:

```
"thetext
"
```

so a carriage return after "thetext".

and my setAttribute will end up looking like:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg" onclick="window.open('https://textfromfile
.example.com')" ;="" type="button" name="buttonname">mybutton</button>
```

So there is a carriage return after "textfromfile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the carriage return exists in the TXT file as well, so of course it is also returned!

However, you can easily strip it using [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```js
mydata = response.trim()
```

(Note that this would also remove trailing *spaces*.)

---

At a side note, instead of setting `onclick` like that, it would be better to set an attribute and have a static click handler that refers to this attribute. Or even better, since it seems you are using Bootstrap: You can use a regular link with `<a class="btn">`, make it open the link in a new window using `target="_blank"` and then just set the `href` attribute from your code.